# In '¿Cómo *le* va?', what is the role of 'le'?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, saludos

What is the role of 'le' in the sentence:

> ¿Cómo **le** va?

And the role of 'te' in '¿Cómo te va?'

What is the role of 'le' and 'te' in the sentences like:

> ¿Qué **te** pasa?

> ¿Qué **le** pasa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Leísmo de cortesía" and consistency](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/le%c3%adsmo-de-cortes%c3%ada-and-consistency)

Comment: I think this post might answer your question better [“Se” and “le” with “usted”, but always “te” with “tú”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28867/5481)

Comment: If anyone really wants to close this as a duplicate, I guess "All about datives" would be better than the two that have been proposed so far.  But I think we should leave this open because it's quite specific, and it's focused on greetings.

Comment: @Diego this is not a "leísmo de cortesía", because all the example sentences have an indirect object, not a direct object. You would not say * *qué la pasa*. I also do not think this is one of those datives in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there (some may say "ethical dative" but I do not think it is that). I think this is a standard indirect object.

Comment: @wimi Retracto mi voto para cerrar. Hice un par de sugerencias al OP, pero no puedo estar seguro de si alguna de ellas responde por completo a su pregunta o no. Estaría bien que clarificara si han ayudado o no, pero en cualquier caso, retracto mi voto y dejo que la comunidad provea de una respuesta adecuada (via post antiguo o nuevo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are *indirect objects*.  You can think of them like this:

- *¿Cómo le/te va?* How is life treating *you*?
- *¿Qué le/te pasa?* What's new with *you*?/What's wrong with *you*?/What's happening to *you*?

*Le* is formal, *te* is informal.  That is, "le" corresponds to *usted* and *te* corresponds to *tú*.

Here is a chart showing subject pronouns and their corresponding indirect object pronouns:

Singular:
First person: yo, me
Second person informal: tú, te
Second person formal: usted, le
Third person: él/ella, le

Plural:
First person: nosotros, nos
Second person formal: ustedes, les
Second person informal: vosotros, os (in Spain)
Second person informal: ustedes, les (in Latin America)
Third person: ellos/ellas, les

An indirect object is something affected by the verb, but not directly acted on by the verb.  For example, *She told me a secret* -- "me" is the indirect object.

Indirect objects in Spanish are similar to English, but not exactly the same.  If you want to learn more about this topic, see [All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26171/9385).

Comment: Gracias por la colaboracion, @wimi.

Answer (score 0):

objeto indirecto , indirect object or complement in all of the cases,

1. le, meaning a él, le va bien, mal, ... but a él.
2. te, le, a ti, a él, le pasa, te pasa, te pasa algo, algo is the direct object or complement, te or le does not refer to a place, so there is not other option, it is indirect complement